# age verfication from user input

Tags: ios

I'm wanting to create a age verification system for iOS

I have a date that a user enters through a UITextField. How do I compare this date with current date to find out if the user is under 18.

Here's what I have done so far but it is only in years obviously peoples age could be less than 18 even if today's year - year of birth = 18;

```
 NSArray *ageArray = [ageString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

    int day = [[ageArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    int month = [[ageArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    int year = [[ageArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

    if(day <= 31 && month <= 12){

        NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
        NSDate* userDate = [df dateFromString:ageString];


        NSDateComponents *otherDay = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:userDate];
        NSDateComponents *today = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

        NSLog(@"%d - %d\n%d", [today year], [otherDay year], ([today year] - [otherDay year]));

        if([today year] - [otherDay year] =< 18) {
            NSLog(@"too young");

            if([today month] < [otherDay month])



        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to simply make a popup saying "By clicking OK you confirm that you are over 18 years of age"?

Comment: What @millimoose said. Or, set the rating of your app to 18+ when you put it on the store.

Comment: Honestly, by now when faced with a day/month/year age gate, I click the "year" checkbox, page down a few times, and press Enter. The only reason why anyone would fill it out truthfully is because they don't realise there's no need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
NSDate *dateA = [NSDate date];
NSDate *dateB = [NSDate date]; //User's age

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:dateA
                                                 toDate:dateB
                                                options:0];

NSLog(@"Difference in date components: %i/%i/%i", components.day, components.month, components.year);

if (components.year < 18) {
    //Under Age
} else {
    //Ok Age
}
```

in that NSLog you'll get the difference between those dates

Comment: What happens when the user enters an age that is past today's date? This could return a negative or even overflowed value, which I wouldn't reccomend.

Comment: i tested it too: `NSDateComponents *componentsS = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
 [componentsS setDay:1200];
 
 NSDate *returnDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:componentsS toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSDate *dateB = returnDate;
    
    NSLog(@"%@", dateB);` It gives 2015, which is a date past today, it only calculates the difference between dates, not negative or positives values.

Comment: if that is the case, than this is not a good solution. Just specifying a date 30 years in the future makes me over 18? I would NEVER use this in my own apps.

Comment: Obviously, you need to test if it's not a future date the user is giving you. How can you put a date in the future in a age field? only if you don't set max date, which is in fact a solution that i will NEVER use on my apps.

Answer (score -2):

This code should convert a NSTimeInterval into days:

```
NSTimeInterval time = [enteredDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];
NSInteger days  = time/60/60/24;
```

Which you could then use to compare to a set number of days.

Comment: Not all years have 60*60*24 seconds. That's not a good thing to assume.

Comment: are youn talking abt daylight saving

Comment: @Ranjit please do not end your posts with `Regards Blah` or `Thanks Blah`, as it clutters up questions. for more info, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/FAQ)